# joining data sets while also comparing null values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two data frames.

DF1

```
column1         column2             column3              column4
agree           strongly agree      disagree             null
null            disagree            strongly disagree    agree
disagree        null                strongly agree       disagree
```

DF2

```
col1            col2                col3                 col4      cluster
disagree        agree               strongly disagree    disagree    1 
agree           strongly agree      disagree             null        2
disagree        null                strongly agree       disagree    5
disagree        agree               strongly agree       disagree    3
null            disagree            strongly disagree    agree       5
disagree        null                strongly agree       disagree    6
```

Expected output

```
column1         column2             column3              column4   Cluster
agree           strongly agree      disagree             null      2
null            disagree            strongly disagree    agree     5
disagree        null                strongly agree       disagree  6
```

I have already did this in R but I could not implement the same in PySpark. Can anyone please tell me how to implement in PySpark

Code I used in R(where it worked):

```
# my columns names were same here
merged <- left_join(df1,df2,by=c('column1','column2','column3','column4'))
```

**Required Result:** All rows of df1 and the last column of df2 joined.

Comment: can you be more specific, which columns do you want to join? how come you ended up with cluster 2 and 5?

Comment: @pltc I have updated the question. I missed the case with cluster 5. So, The merge should be in such a way that I have all the rows from df1 and the cluster row from df2 joined to df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to pltc's answer, you can also use [`eqNullSafe()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html#pyspark-sql-column-eqnullsafe) which would result in the same output.

```py
data1_sdf. \
    join(data2_sdf, 
         [data1_sdf.c1.eqNullSafe(data2_sdf.c1), 
          data1_sdf.c2.eqNullSafe(data2_sdf.c2), 
          data1_sdf.c3.eqNullSafe(data2_sdf.c3), 
          data1_sdf.c4.eqNullSafe(data2_sdf.c4)],
         'left'
         ). \
    select(data1_sdf['*'], 'cluster'). \
    show()

# +--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
# |      c1|            c2|               c3|      c4|cluster|
# +--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
# |   agree|strongly agree|         disagree|    null|      2|
# |disagree|          null|   strongly agree|disagree|      5|
# |disagree|          null|   strongly agree|disagree|      6|
# |    null|      disagree|strongly disagree|   agree|      5|
# +--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Since join won't take care of null values, I'm thinking about a small hack by replacing all `null`s with a specific value, then perform a left join to keep app df1's records

df1

```
df1 = spark.read.csv('a.csv', header=True).fillna('xxxyyyzzz')
df1.show()

+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+
|  column1|       column2|          column3|  column4|
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+
|    agree|strongly agree|         disagree|xxxyyyzzz|
|xxxyyyzzz|      disagree|strongly disagree|    agree|
| disagree|     xxxyyyzzz|   strongly agree| disagree|
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+
```

df2

```
df2 = spark.read.csv('b.csv', header=True).fillna('xxxyyyzzz')
df2.show()

+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------+
|  column1|       column2|          column3|  column4|cluster|
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------+
| disagree|         agree|strongly disagree| disagree|      1|
|    agree|strongly agree|         disagree|xxxyyyzzz|      2|
| disagree|     xxxyyyzzz|   strongly agree| disagree|      5|
| disagree|         agree|   strongly agree| disagree|      3|
|xxxyyyzzz|      disagree|strongly disagree|    agree|      5|
| disagree|     xxxyyyzzz|   strongly agree| disagree|      6|
+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------+
```

Join and return dummy value back to nulls

```
(df1
    .join(df2, on=df1.columns, how='left')
    .replace('xxxyyyzzz', None)
    .show()
)

+--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
| column1|       column2|          column3| column4|cluster|
+--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
|   agree|strongly agree|         disagree|    null|      2|
|    null|      disagree|strongly disagree|   agree|      5|
|disagree|          null|   strongly agree|disagree|      6|
|disagree|          null|   strongly agree|disagree|      5|
+--------+--------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to replace this nulls with some values as @pltc suggested you may consider to use monotonically_increasing_id() instead of just constant. During sort merge join records with the same values are going to be moved to the same machine to do the join, in case of monotonically_increasing_id() the dummy values are going to be evenly distributed which may be good for the performance

```
 //use such function to salt nulls
def salt(column: Column): Column =
    when(column.isNull, concat(lit("null_prefix_"), monotonicall_increasing_id()))
    .otherwsie(column)


//Then do the join as usuall

//Then unsalt before select with this function

def unSalt(column: Column): Column =
    when(column.startsWith("null_prefix_"), concat(lit(null)))
    .otherwsie(column)
```